# My React bootstrap routed page path doesn't work after refreshing in live

Tags: reactjs, router, react-bootstrap, react-router-dom

In this URL you can see this issue: http://qconstruct.in/contact

This is code link from code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-hypatia-3pre9
It seems the output is working fine in code sandbox.
But my hosted website is not working after refreshing other routed pages

I using **React Router Bootstrap**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch  } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Comment: How you are hosting your app?

Comment: have you used node js in server side

Comment: No, now I didn't used any server side codes. Its only frontend. @iamwebkalakaar

Comment: I hosted my website in Hostgator. (multidomain shared hosting) @ZohaibIjaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is on server side.

Refer this link:
https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

I had appache server in my hosting, so I added the below code in my "***.htaccess***" file which was in root path of my website.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

It works!.
Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `.htaccess` file in root of your build

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It seems the issue is at hosting side. Because the same routing I created and hosted in Firebase, there it's working fine, the bookmark url works.
But ony in hostgator hosting it has issue on routing refresh error.
If it can fix by adding '.htaccess' means, then how to do it exactly?